# Lowercase columns by name using dataframe method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing strings and NaNs. I want to `str.lower()` certain columns by name `to_lower = ['b', 'd', 'e']`. Ideally I could do it with a method on the whole dataframe, rather than with a method on `df[to_lower]`. I have

`df[to_lower] = df[to_lower].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())`

but I would like a way to do it without assigning to the selected columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'a'], 'b': ['B', 'b']})
to_lower = ['a']
df2 = df.copy()
df2[to_lower] = df2[to_lower].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Comment: Your method doesn't assign the result to the selected columns. It returns a new data frame. If you want to assign them to new columns, `df[new_columns] = df[to_lower].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())`?

Comment: @Psidom yes that's what i meant, edited question

Comment: If you don't want to change the `to_lower` columns, just provide new column names as `new_columns`.

Comment: Example input and output data?

Comment: @Psidom My code above does what I want, but I want a way to do it as a method on `df`, so I don't have to assign to `df[lower]`, not to avoid overwriting those columns, but because I want to do it as method chaining on `df` rather than on a subset of it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Added example. The code works, it's just not in the style of chaining that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign` method and unpack the result as keyword argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'a'], 'b': ['B', 'b'], 'c': ['C', 'c']})
to_lower = ['a', 'b']

df.assign(**df[to_lower].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower()))

#   a   b   c
#0  a   b   C
#1  a   b   c
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the `df` name inside `assign`, so I can do it in the middle of a chain of methods?

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
for column in to_lower:
    df[column] = df[column].str.lower()
```

This is far more efficient assuming you have more rows than columns.

Comment: Is it possible to do this returning a new dataframe rather than mutating the original?